# Debuggin in Grails 2.4.4. IDE Groovy/Grails Tool suite

Tags: grails, grails-2.0

How to debug my code in grails 2.4.4?

Any command is there to run as debug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run your application by right click on project select **debug-as** and then **run-app**

and I guess you can also use these commands to debug grails application

```
grails run-app --debug
```

or for forked execution

```
grails run-app --debug-fork
```

follow this link to know more

http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.3.x/guide/commandLine.html

thanks.

Comment: Hai, @Arshul, thanking you :) I have right click and debug as run-app, then Breakpoint set in IDE.